# Matrix Similarity for All Scalars

Tags: matrices

Show that if matrix $A$ is similar to $B$, then $A-\lambda I_n$ is similar to $B-\lambda I_n$, for all scalars $\lambda$.

Comment: What is the definition of a similar matrix? If you write this down, it may become clear what the natural thing to do/check is.

Comment: they have the same eigenvalues with same algebraic and geometric multiplicities, same det and trace, same characteristic polynomial, same rank and nullity

Comment: $A,B$ are similar if there is some invertible $V$ such that $AV = VB$. Note that $VI = IV$ (not Roman numerals :-)). No need for any eigenvalues, multiplicities or any of that namby-pamby stuff.

Comment: I'm still confused

Comment: @Debun: those are *properties* which similar matrices share. The *definition* of similarity given by copper.hat can be used to show what you want to show (see Dave's answer below).

Answer (score 2):

Let $A,B\in\Bbb K^{n\times n}$ and $\lambda\in\Bbb K$. For $A$ and $B$ to be similar, there must exist an invertible matrix $P\in\Bbb K^{n\times n}$ such that $P^{-1}AP=B$. Now using the properties of matrix multiplication and inverses, we have:
$$P^{-1}(A-\lambda I_n)P=P^{-1}AP-P^{-1}(\lambda I_n)P=B-\lambda(P^{-1}I_nP)=B-\lambda(P^{-1}P)=B-\lambda I_n$$
Therefore, $A-\lambda I_n$ is similar to $B-\lambda I_n$.